# Springboot - Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/htm

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I see a number of answers to this question previously but none of the solutions I have tried worked.

My `login.css` is not getting applied to `login.html` in my Spring Boot application. I am also using Thymeleaf.

Security is turned on - but I do not think this is the issue as in the browser. I do not see a failure to load `login.css` - only the message:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Further inspection in the browser shows it is requesting `text/css`, but getting a `text/html` response.

The html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatiable" content="IE-Edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="Login"/>


<title>LOGIN</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

....
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" content-type="text/css"/>
```

The path for the `login.html`

```
\src\main\resources\templates\login.html
```

The path for `login.css`

```
\src\main\resources\static\login.css
```

And just in case it was a permissions issue I put:

```
.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
```

I noted there is no issue with all the css delivered via CDN. Also the browser is returning the `login.css` with a **302 status code**.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same issue while writing some code with **Spring Boot + Spring MVC**. The CSS files set using a CDN worked fine, while the CSS file set from my `static/css` folder returned a HTML content.

Example:

```
<!-- This first worked fine, loading all styles -->
<link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
      href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

<!-- This second one returned the content of an HTML - Content Type text/html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/login/style.css}" href="/css/login/style.css" />
```

After a while I could see using **Chrome Dev Tools** that the content returned for my local `style.css` was the same as one of my HTML pages.

Inspecting the route that pointed to the HTML file with that content, I could realise I was using the wrong property for the `@RequestMapping` configuration. I had `@RequestMapping(name="...")`, instead of `@RequestMapping(path="...")`.

**Controller with the problem**

```
@RequestMapping(name = "/product/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("product", new Product());
    return "product/edit";
}
```

**Controller changed**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/product/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String add(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("product", new Product());

    return "product/edit";
}
```

After changing the property `name` with `path` everything started to load correctly.

It was strange how a small mistake like this affected my whole program.

Hope it's somehow useful for someone who faces the same issue.

Comment: I was using @GetMapping and replaced it with `@RequestMapping(path=..., method= RequestMethod.GET)` but no success for me, still the same error :(

Comment: similar mistake for me I had an `@GetMapping()` without any path value and it caused same issue

Answer (score 1):

This how i fixed this issue:

I put my css files in :

```
/static/css/login.css
```

etc

Then in the html it was referenced as :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Thanks. Out!

Answer (score 1):

---

## A SMALL PROBLEM THAT CAN BE TIME COSTLY

---

IDK if my problem is strictly personal, or if other developers often experience the same issues, but I seem to always have trouble at the same point when learning a new backend framework: Each time I learn a framework I always get stuck trying to figure out how link my `stylesheets` to my `HTML` Documents, and how to properly configure the project to handle the request for the `CSS` made by the `HTML`   ` tag. my styles-sheets that link to my HTML documents. This was the same issue I had when learning **PHP's Laravel** and Node's **Express JS**.

Personally, I have always found that the easiest way to configure a project to handle HTTP requests for documents living in a filesystem  is to symply have a base directory that all the `HTML`, `CSS`, & frontend `JS` documents can be dropped into — much like a standard raw server does (i.e. Nginx & Apache).

###### Turns out, thats how Spring Boot works!

So I assume you also figured this out since your reading a question that asks about serving CSS. I mean, you wouldn't want to serve CSS unless you were successfully serving HTML documents first.

If you're familiar with a typical server like **Apache**, I good way to look at *Spring Boot*, and serving static files, is by looking at the ***`Resources`*** folder as your **`/var/www/html`** directory.

Its important to understand 3 things when creating your Static Filesystem with Spring Boot.

1. If you made changes to your files, rebuild the project, and then refresh the browser, you might be supprised to find everything working.
2. If your trying to route any static files via a controller, stop! That is not how Spring Boot was intended to be used. Your controllers are for logic, not routing. Only use your resource folders static directory, when serving static files.
3. Last, but far from leaset, You need to get your static directory organized correctly, bellow are some snippets to help.

##### Here is a File System Tree of how I configure my Static Directory.

```
.
└── resources/
    │
    └── static/
        │
        ├── css/
        │   ├── index.css
        │   ├── alpha.css
        │   └── beta.css    
        │
        ├── html/
        │   ├── index.html
        │   ├── alpha.html
        │   └── beta.html
        │
        │
        └── templates
            └──── /* Your template files are not
                      important for this topic*/
```

###### Above you can see I created two directories for static documents.

---

1. ###### A directory for HTML documents.
2. ###### A directory for CSS stylesheets.

###### Here is what it looks like in **IntelliJ**

[image]

Now, when you use the `<link rel="" href="">` tag to link your style sheets you are going to want to enter the correct URL. If the URL is invalid, and your using IntelliJ, you will get a warning, otherwise, you might find things, simply not working.

Here is what the File tree looks like, with the full relevent-filepaths instead of the file names. The values are the correct vulues that you would want to add to a `link` tag's `href` attribute  (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/.../file.css">`)

```
    ./resources/
    │   
    ├── ./static/templates
    │   |
    │   └──  /* Again, template paths are
    |       not relevent for this topic */
    │
    └── ./static/
        │
        ├── ./static/css/
        │   ├── ./static/css/index.css
        │   ├── ./static/css/alpha.css
        │   └── ./static/css/beta.css    
        │
        └── ./static/html/
            ├── ./static/html/index.html
            ├── ./static/html/alpha.html
            └── ./static/html/beta.html
```

###### so if your were building this project, each of the `./static/html/<filename>.html/css` file paths would be valid to add to a `<link>` tag's `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was defining more than a controller method that returns the same `ModelAndView`

```
@GetMapping("/home")
fun home(model: ModelMap): ModelAndView {
    model.addAttribute("model", SomeModel())
    return ModelAndView("home", model)
}

@GetMapping
fun index(model: ModelMap): ModelAndView {
    model.addAttribute("model", SomeModel())
    return ModelAndView("home", model)
}
```

Removing one of the methods solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This type of error may happened because the server **had an error... in my case, file did not exist on the server**

In my case the server response MIME TYPE was 'application/json', perhaps because it's an error.

Also my application does not properly manage errors at this time.

Good luck!